# How to inject any js file inside head tag in Laravel v9.19 in development server?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, vite, laravel-vite

I'm using Laravel v9.19 and Vite v4.0.0. When I'm adding `config.js` file using `@vite` directive, it is always executing after all the html content is loaded. But, I'm trying to execute `config.js` file before all the html content is loaded. The purpose is, I'm trying to access the configuration values immediately after body tag is loaded. Is there any way I can include `config.js` file inside head tag?

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import VitePluginEntryInject from 'vite-plugin-entry-inject';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        VitePluginEntryInject({
            // head-prepend/head/body-prepend/body
            injectTo: 'head'
        }),
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/scss/theme.scss', 
                'resources/scss/user.scss', 
                'resources/js/config.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

welcome.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>
       
        @vite('resources/js/config.js')

    </head>
    <body>
      <script>
        console.log(window.config);
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

config.js

```
const config = {
  mode: 'dark'
}

window.config = config;
```

I want to load config.js file inside head tag that I can access config values inside html marukup.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify a `vite.config.js` adding the build section like that:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import VitePluginEntryInject from 'vite-plugin-entry-inject';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        VitePluginEntryInject({
            // head-prepend/head/body-prepend/body
            injectTo: 'head'
        }),
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/scss/theme.scss', 
                'resources/scss/user.scss', 
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                main: './resources/js/main.js',
                config: './resources/js/config.js'
            },
        },
    },
});
```

And as a result in your blade file, you can do like that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel</title>

        <script type="module" src="{{ mix('assets/js/config.js') }}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <script>
        console.log(window.config);
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After adding this config.js not found in dev server. Is there anything I can do here?
```<script type="module" src="{{ mix('assets/js/config.js') }}"></script>```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: vite.config.js

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import VitePluginEntryInject from 'vite-plugin-entry-inject';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        VitePluginEntryInject({
            // head-prepend/head/body-prepend/body
            injectTo: 'head'
        }),
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/scss/theme.scss', 
                'resources/scss/user.scss', 
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Add this to your app.js:

```js
import './config.js'
```